# My self-signed APK got Blocked by Play Protect

Tags: apk, self-signed, apksigner, apk-signing

I am a home user working on Windows 7 X64. I have a problem with my signed APK.
My app is only for home use and learning. I won't submit to Google Play.
When installed, it shows

> Blocked by Play Protect.
> Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer.
> Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.

**Tools:**

```
keytool.exe    v8.0.3019.9
openssl.exe    v1.1.1k
zipalign.exe   v29.0.3
apksigner.jar  v29.0.3
```

**Batch Script:**

```
cls


del /f KEY.JKS
del /f KEY.PEM
del /f KEY.PK8
del /f CERT.PEM


"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\keytool.exe" -genkeypair -v -alias MYKEY -storepass 123456 -keypass 123456 -keystore KEY.JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9999 -dname "EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US"

openssl.exe    req    -x509   -nodes    -days 9999   -newkey rsa:2048  -keyout KEY.PEM  -out CERT.PEM  -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Android/OU=Android/CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com"  -config openssl.cnf
openssl.exe    pkcs8  -topk8  -nocrypt  -inform PEM  -outform DER      -in KEY.PEM      -out KEY.PK8


zipalign.exe   -f -p 4   myApp.apk  myApp_Align.apk


rem java -jar apksigner.jar  sign    --ks  KEY.JKS  --ks-pass pass:123456  --out myApp_Signed.apk  myApp_Align.apk
    java -jar apksigner.jar  sign    --key KEY.PK8  --cert CERT.PEM        --out myApp_Signed.apk  myApp_Align.apk

    java -jar apksigner.jar  verify  -v  --print-certs                           myApp_Signed.apk


pause
```

**My key got blocked:**

```
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 07d51277869be18dfe8618d797ad1c0c8e16b7c067d9d224962af960c0382bfb
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 85789690f7f12d0d6f4c7f67adb96429c326049f
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 13b9633388142f4d40295cd45ac65aa9
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: bb280251b6eb2a1dd5e2493a3ac23881e254274318a2247bce84fd067181c441
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: b2be0f31d13ce91162bf7ccf9fa4662e7c47b2d6
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 9648bca600a81a383cffd490a8614852
```

**I downloaded some APK from the internet and it doesn't get blocked.**

```
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: ef57b690165cb561b5026922c00d2d6574e8b184fa7d161e076f06e06e6d35db
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 0c2440c055c753a8f0493b4e602d3ea0096b1023
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 452f8cfe026b30a8a3e99a6074e5f285
```

**I downloaded KEY.PK8 and CERT.PEM from the internet and it doesn't get blocked.**

```
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=lorenz@londatiga.net, CN=Lorensius W. L. T, OU=AndroidDev, O=Londatiga, L=Bandung, ST=Jawa Barat, C=ID
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 518ac8bdaf0c767deb31bae1eba826adbef793a68f22784cf3e19c67ba87ecb9
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: ece521e38c5e9cbea53503eaef1a6ddd204583fa
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: eea6f6f40858b8215c48b0465fe479b8
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 1024
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: d8dc2ef9b37fcb543b07678a2d64d3a1dc5122642ee824a61dfbed0bf86d25c4
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 74bd7b456d9e651fc84446f65041bef1207c408d
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 58d291bc49e568eb8fc84dabaf508d08
```

What's wrong with my steps? I switched to keystore (KEY.JKS), it didn't work too.

Comment: `518ac8bdaf0c767deb31bae1eba826adbef793a68f22784cf3e19c67ba87ecb9` is compromized / stolen

Comment: `a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc` is testkey.x509.pem from source build/master/target/product/security which doesn't block by Play Protect. It's 13 years ago.

Comment: `CN=Android Debug, OU=Android, O=US, L=US, ST=US, C=US` is the debug.keystore from  Eclipse or Android Studio which doesn't block by Play Protect too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless google knows your key's fingerprint or the APK itself is signed with a google key, it gets flagged by play protect as "unknown developer". You can "verify" your key by submitting an application signed by that particular key on google play

Comment: So sad, Google Play developer account cost $25.

Comment: A developer can submit APK with default DN , right ?

         EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US

Comment: I am not sure. Though google is enforcing the use of google managed keys.